# How can I change correctly the parameters in the query string for a URL after the event handler onclick?

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the parameters in the query string. I wish to have this effect: If I click the first time, the query-string changes, and if I click the second time, the query string changes again. I would to like have this effect for all elements  and must be independent of each other. In the my code below, I don't have what I would like. because If I click the first element, its query-string changes, but now If i click the second element nothing happening, I have to click it two times to change its query string. Don't worry for the refresh page after click, because it will be ajax call. I just need to understand how to change the parameters correctly. I apologize if the request is not clear. Thanks for your help.

```
<a href="quantity-0" onclick="updateParams(this)">CHANGE PARAMETERS<a/><br><br>
<a href="quantity-0" onclick="updateParams(this)">CHANGE PARAMETERS<a/><br><br>
<a href="quantity-0" onclick="updateParams(this)">CHANGE PARAMETERS<a/><br><br>


<script>
 var clicked = true;
 function updateParams(abba){
     if(clicked){
        var a = abba.href.replace('quantity-0', 'add-0');
        abba.setAttribute('href', a);
    }else{
        var a = abba.href.replace('add-0','quantity-0');
        abba.setAttribute('href',a);
  }
     clicked = !clicked;
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
<script>
    function updateParams(abba){
        if(abba.href.search('quantity-0') > -1) {
            var a = abba.href.replace('quantity-0', 'add-0');
            abba.setAttribute('href', a);
        }
        else {
            var a = abba.href.replace('add-0','quantity-0');
            abba.setAttribute('href',a);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this using closures:

```
<a href="quantity-0" onclick="makeUpdater(this)">CHANGE PARAMETERS<a/><br><br>
<a href="quantity-0" onclick="makeUpdater(this)">CHANGE PARAMETERS<a/><br><br>
<a href="quantity-0" onclick="makeUpdater(this)">CHANGE PARAMETERS<a/><br><br>


<script>
 fucntion makeUpdater(abba) {
   var clicked = true;
   return function updateParams(){
     if(clicked){
        var a = abba.href.replace('quantity-0', 'add-0');
        abba.setAttribute('href', a);
    }else{
        var a = abba.href.replace('add-0','quantity-0');
        abba.setAttribute('href',a);
    }
    clicked = !clicked;
  };
}
</script>
```

the problem was that you've had one variable for all buttons. You need separated for each one of them.